# How to include two2 sum ranges in SUMIFS (excel)

Tags: excel, max, countif, sumifs

[image]

Hi everyone,

What I want to achieve in this task is:

- If `AAPL` appeared the most in the winning category, then the `Best performance` will be `AAPL` regardless of whether the total P/L (total P/L for winning & lossing) for `AAPL` is higher or lower than `ROKU`. For example in the screenshot above, `AAPL` appeared 4 times in winning category with total P/L of `151.5` while `ROKU` appeared 2 times with total P/L of `187`. So the `Best performance` will be `AAPL` instead of `ROKU` even though the P/L for `ROKU` is higher.
- However, if the frequency for both `AAPL` and `ROKU` appeared in the winning category are the same, then the `Best performance` will be determined by total P/L. So in this case, if the total P/L for `ROKU` is still higher than `AAPL`, then the `Best performance` will be `ROKU`.

I tried to use `SUMIFS` but it only allow me to have a sum range which result in `291.5`. The formulas in cell `H6` is `=IF(B6:B215<>"",COUNTIF(B6:B215,B6:B215),"")`, cell `I6` is `=MAX(H6:H215)` and cell `J6` is `=MAX(SUMIFS(C6:C215,B6:B215,B6:B215,H6:H215,$I$6))` as shown in the screenshot above. I think what I did is not a right one but I'm not sure what can be modified. The correct output should be the answers in cell `C2:C3`.

Please give me some advice on how should I modify my formulas in order to achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

### Edit

[image]

- List item

Comment: How `Total P/L` is `151.5`? What is logic as per your screenshot?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, total P/L for winning and lossing. Which is `=C6+C7+C10+C11+F8+F9`

Comment: Ok. got it. I didn't notice `AMD` I count is as `AAPL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with any helping column if you have <kbd>Excel O365</kbd>. Try below formula to `C2` cell

```
=@LET(x,INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,UNIQUE(B6:B11),COUNTIF(B6:B11,UNIQUE(B6:B11)),SUMIF(B6:B11,UNIQUE(B6:B11),C6:C11)+SUMIF(E6:E11,UNIQUE(B6:B11),F6:F11))&"</s></t>","//s"),TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(B6:B11))+1,2))),SORTBY(x,INDEX(x,,2),-1,INDEX(x,,3),-1))
```

Then put below formula to `C3` cell

```
=SUMIF(B6:B11,C2,C6:C11)+SUMIF(E6:E11,C2,F6:F11)
```

[image]

> Edit: Try below formulas as per my screenshot with helping columns for Non 365 version of excel.

```
H6=IF($B$6:$B$11<>"",COUNTIF($B$6:$B$11,$B$6:$B$11),"")
I6=SUMIF($B$6:$B$11,B6,$C$6:$C$11)+SUMIF($E$6:$E$11,B6,$F$6:$F$11)
J6=H6*10^MAX($H$6:$H$11)+I6
C2=INDEX(IF(J6:J11=MAX(J6:J11),B6:B11,""),1) -->Array entry (CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER)
C3=SUMIF(B6:B11,C2,C6:C11)+SUMIF(E6:E11,C2,F6:F11)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I'm doing this for 100+ users. I'm not able to guarantee every user has Excel 365. Do you have other method without using function in excel 365?

Comment: Then we have to go with helper column like you used `H` column.

Comment: ya, I'm still thinking on other method to work on this issue with the help of helper column

Comment: I think it should work well, the only thing is if I change cell `B11` to `ROKU`, then cell `C2` will not show anything. I guess this is because of the `Row_num` in `INDEX`

Comment: Make sure you entered `INDEX(...)` formula as array entry. `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: yes, i'm using array entry. I guess that is because of the row num in `INDEX`. I attached my screenshot under the edit section in my question. In this case, the first row is actually empty.

Comment: Can you please try this `=INDEX(B6:B11,SMALL(IF(J6:J11=MAX(J6:J11),ROW(B6:B11)-ROW(B5),""),1))`

Comment: Yes, it work perfectly now:). Thank you very much! May I know what is the reason that cause you to use the formula in cell `J6`?

Comment: Without it you can't detect highest value winner.

Comment: I found out that the way you did will not always working if there is an extremely high P/L in Winning category. I attached the screenshot under `Edit` where it show an example where the output is wrong. The correct answer should be `AAPL` instead of `TSM`.

Comment: Then make it 100 instead of 10 like `H6*100^MAX....`

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach for the Excel 365 version:

```
=INDEX(LET(UNIQUES,UNIQUE(B6:B11),SORTBY(UNIQUES,COUNTIF(B6:B11,UNIQUES),-1,SUMIF(B6:B11,UNIQUES,C6:C11)+SUMIF(E6:E11,UNIQUES,F6:F11),-1)),1)
```

[image]

If one of the AAPL in the first column is changed to ROKU

[image]

The pre-365 equivalent of the above formula should be:

```
=INDEX(
IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11),
MATCH(
MAX(
COUNTIF(B6:B11,IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11))*10^4+SUMIF(B6:B11,IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11),C6:C11)+SUMIF(E6:E11,IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),  MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11),F6:F11)
),
COUNTIF(B6:B11,IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11))*10^4+SUMIF(B6:B11,IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11),C6:C11)+SUMIF(E6:E11,IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0))>0,B6:B11),F6:F11),0)
)
```

where I have used Frequency to simulate Unique and have multiplied the Countif by 10^4 before adding it to the Sumif's to simulate Sortby with two sort keys.

Comment: Thanks for your input, do you have any method that can be used for non Excel 365 version?

Comment: I think so - use Frequency instead of Unique and a workaround to replace Sortby. Will add to my answer, but I can't actually test it in Excel pre-365.

Comment: I think if the function is available in Excel pre-365 then should be fine, I can test it out. Initially I tried to use `=INDEX(B6:B11,MODE.MULT(IFNA(MATCH(B6:B11,B6:B11,0),"")))` to get the mode in column `B6:B11`, but I realized `MODE.MULT` is not working in Excel pre-365.